# Android Download Manager after targeting app from 28 to 29 - setDestinationInExternalPublicDir() - Not one of standard directories: MyDir/videos/

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-10.0, android-storage, scoped-storage

I have application on play store with targeting version 28. And in app I have used Download Manager which downloads files to custom directory. And now as per play store requirement policy app target version should be updated to 29. Consequently, I have updated to 29 but after that when I am trying to download file download manager is giving following error in **Android 10(Q)**.

**Not one of standard directories: MyDir/videos/**

I have read some solutions for it and seen that it allows storing in only public directories like DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, DIRECTORY_DCIM etc. But the problem is, in current live app its reading from MyDir/videos/ where users' current downloaded data is stored and if I change path to other directory that will cause so many issues. So I am looking for solution using which I can download files in the custom directory same as current live version. I have attached my code that I used in app to download files.

Code:

```
 DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(servicestring);
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
 request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
 request.setTitle(Title);
 request.setDescription(Description);
 request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("MyDir/videos/", filename);            
 request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
 request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
 Long reference = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Dont use DownloadManager then.

Comment: @blackapps, I can't remove it now. As there is already many things connected to it. Isn't there any solution exists?

Comment: I can not image what all could be connected to using DownloadManager. But a la.. Download to .../Documents/MyDir/videos. When done move the file to .../MyDir/videos.

Comment: @blackapps, Yes, that is the last solution I thought of.